# Installing tarball package of the latest version of Firefox for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: firefox

Currently I have Ubuntu 12.04 version and current version of the firefox I have is 21.0. I have downloaded "firefox-26.0.tar.bz2", can you please let me know what is the command to install Firefox 26 version?

Comment: Why not update it with `apt-get`? according to [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/26.0+build2-0ubuntu0.12.04.2), 12.04 should have Firefox version 26

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple(since you don't have an internet connection on ubuntu computer), I have converted the firefox installation to .deb, which is very easy to install(just double-click it, the ubuntu software centar will open, wait a little, and it will show the install button). For this, you don't need an internet connection. You can download .deb file from my personal cloud from [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=5E44BE5905B5EBD0!806). I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

First open a Terminal and navigate to a folder where it is located to unpack it using `cd` for example:

`cd /home/yourusername/Desktop/firefox-26.0.tar.bz2`

then run:

`tar xvjf firefox-26.0.tar.bz2`

after:

`./configure`

`make`

`sudo make install`

(for this actually I recommend to use Checkinstall, I'm using it myself)

and instead of:

`sudo make install`

you will use:

`sudo checkinstall`

The cons of Checkinstall is that CheckInstall keeps track of all files installed by a "make install" or equivalent, creates a Slackware, RPM, or Debian package with those files, and adds it to the installed packages database, allowing for easy package removal or distribution.